# .toggleClass not working inside function

Tags: javascript, jquery

When I put `$("header nav ul").toggleClass("open")` outside of the on click function it works, but it doesn't when I put it inside. Why is that??

The alert method is running, so clicking the a tag works.

```
    <header>
        <div class="wrapper">
            <h1 class="logo">Blesto</h1>
            <nav>
                <a href="" class="burger-nav"></a>
                <h2>Main Navigation</h2>
                <ul class="burger-nav-ul">
                    <li><a href="">Our Story</a></li>
                    <li><a href="">Menu</a></li>
                    <li><a href="">Reservations</a></li>
                    <li><a href="">News</a></li>
                    <li><a href="">Reviews</a></li>
                </ul>
            </nav>
        </div>
    </header>

$(document).ready(function(){
    $(".burger-nav").click(function(){
        alert("hi");
        $("header nav ul").toggleClass("open");
    });
});
```

Comment: It redirect to same page, right?

Comment: Where is the header tag on your HTML?

Comment: What does open class?

Answer (score 3):

You need to stop the default behavior of anchor element.

```
$(".burger-nav").click(function(event){
    event.preventDefault();
    alert("hi");
    $("header nav ul").toggleClass("open");
});
```

You are right about `alert` being run, but then the default behavior is run which is going to wherever `href` points to. In this case, the same page.

Comment: You can also just ditch href="".  Since you're adding a .click event, you dont need it.